# Function to replace double line breaks with paragraph tags not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, function

I have a function to replace double line breaks with paragraph tags, but alas - it's not working for me:

```
'Function to replace double line breaks with paragraph tags

Function fixParas(srcText As String) As String
    fixParas = srcText
    If len(fixParas) > 0 Then
        fixParas = Replace(VbCrLf , "<br />")
        fixParas = Replace("<br>" , "<br />")
        fixParas = Replace("<br/>" , "<br />")
        fixParas = Replace("<br /><br />" , "</p><p>")
        fixParas = Replace("<br /></p>" , "</p>")
        fixParas = Replace("<p><br />" , "<p>")
    End If
End Function
```

As far as I'm aware, the syntax is correct, but it doesn't like something.

Comment: Try `fixParas = fixParas.Replace...`

Comment: What Replace is this? VB6 compatibility requires 3 parameters. VB.NET wants the string instance.

Comment: @Steve - What do you mean?

Comment: @BanForFun : You should write that as the answer.

Comment: @VisualVincent - Done :)

Comment: @BanForFun : Also, what Steve means is that he should get a compiling error since he doesn't use the sufficient amount of parameters. See [the Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: @VisualVincent - Yeap! I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
fixParas = fixParas.Replace...
```

Comment: Fixed! Thanks very much @BanForFun